# Gulp4 problem with output file main.min.js after concat

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, concatenation, minify

I have problem with my output file `main.min.js` in Gulp4. 
I think it's a problem with concatenation

My path files:

```
const config = {
    app: {
        js: [
            './src/js/**/*.js',
        ],
        scss: './src/sass/**/*.scss',
        fonts: './src/fonts/*',
        images: './src/images/*.*',
        html: './src/*.html'
    },
    dist: {
        base: './dist/',
        js: './dist/js',
        css: './dist/css/',
        fonts: './dist/fonts',
        images: './dist/images'
    },
    extraBundles: [
        './dist/main.js',
        './dist/main.css'
    ]
}
```

I use these:

```
const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
```

There is my task:

```
function jsTask(done) {
    src(config.app.js)
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
        }))
        .pipe(concat('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(dest(config.dist.js))
    done();
}
```

In index.html last lines before `<html>` and `<body>`:

```
<script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
```

I see that it took all js files but unfortunately not working.
The output file look like:

```
"use strict";function RecaptchaClearMsg(){document.querySelector(".g-recaptcha").focus()}$(function(){var a={};document.querySelectorAll(".form-data").forEach(function(e){a[e.getAttribute("name")]=e});var i=document.querySelector(".g-recaptcha"),c=function(e,t){return"Pole "+e+" musi zawierać co najmniej "+t+" znaki."},l=function(e,t){return"Pole "+e+" może zawierać co najwyżej "+t+" znaków."},s=function(e){return"Pole "+e+" nie może być puste."},u=function(e){return"Pole "+e+" jest niepoprawne."},r="W formularzu występują błędy.",f="Potwierdź, że nie jesteś robotem.",n=$("#contact-form"),d=document.querySelector(".emailFormAlert");function t(e){if("boolean"!=typeof e)throw new TypeError("State must be a boolean");if(!0===e)n.fadeIn(),n.attr("aria-hidden","false"),m.focus();else{for(var t in n.fadeOut(),n.attr("aria-hidden","true"),a)a[t].value="";grecaptcha.reset(),p.focus()}}var o=$("#close-contact-btn"),p=$("#open-contact-btn");p.click(function(){t(!0)}),o.click(function(){t(!1)});var m=$(".form-data:first");function g(e,t){if(!e.classList.contains("wrongInput")){var n=document.createElement("p");n.classList.add("error"),n.classList.add("wrongInput"),n.textContent=t,e.parentElement.append(n),e.classList.add("wrongInput"),e.addEventListener("focus",h)}}function h(){this.classList.remove("wrongInput"),this.parentElement.removeChild(this.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("error")[0]),d.innerHTML=""}"#contact-form"===document.location.hash&&(p.focus(),p.click()),o.on("keydown",function(e){9!==e.which||e.shiftKey||(e.preventDefault(),m.focus())}),m.on("keydown",function(e){9===e.which&&e.shiftKey&&(e.preventDefault(),o.focus())}),n.on("keydown",function(e){27===e.which&&t(!1)}),$(".emailFormSubmit").click(function(e){if(d.innerHTML='<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x fa-fw"></i>',e.preventDefault(),!0===function(){var e=!0;for(var t in a){var n=a[t].parentElement.innerText;if(!0===a[t].validity.valueMissing)g(a[t],s(n.toLowerCase()));else if(!0===a[t].validity.tooShort){var o=a[t].getAttribute("minlength");g(a[t],c(n.toLowerCase(),o))}else if(!0===a[t].validity.tooLong){var r=a[t].getAttribute("maxlength");g(a[t],l(n.toLowerCase(),r))}else!0===a[t].validity.typeMismatch&&g(a[t],u(n.toLowerCase()));!1===a[t].validity.valid&&(e=!1)}0===grecaptcha.getResponse().length&&(g(i,f),e=!1);return e}()){var t={"g-recaptcha-response":grecaptcha.getResponse()};for(var n in grecaptcha.reset(),a)t[n]=a[n].value;var o=$.ajax({type:"POST",url:document.querySelector(".emailForm").getAttribute("action"),dataType:"json",data:t});o.fail(function(e){console.log(e),d.innerHTML=r}),o.done(function(e){console.log(e),d.innerHTML="Message was sent. Thank you!"})}else d.innerHTML=r}),window.recaptchaClearErr=function(){document.querySelector(".g-recaptcha").focus()}});var myLightbox=GLightbox({selector:"glightboxTest"});$("#toggle").click(function(){$(this).toggleClass("active"),$("#overlay").toggleClass("open")});var typed=new Typed("#typing-element",{strings:['Hello, my name is Filip Handzel.<br>I graduated from Jan Matejko Academy of Fine Arts in Krakow.<br>I like programming, design, electronic and robotic art.<br> I would like to be junior front-end developer!<br><br><br>Click <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href="filiphandzel-cv.pdf">here</a> to download my CV'],typeSpeed:60,startDelay:1e3,loop:!1});
```

Comment: What's wrong exactly?

Comment: @AhmadAlfy I don't know. When I used only `main.min.js` script it does not work, but if I use each in index.html `<script>` js file separately for example `example1.js`, `example2.js`, `example3.js` then it work.

Comment: And you are using no es6 features that would mess up gulp-uglify?  Which I don't believe supports es6.  But you should get an error message in that case.   I would try https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-terser.